# What does Ord mean in Ramda's type annotation?

Tags: functional-programming, ramda.js

Ramda's [documentation for clamp](http://ramdajs.com/0.21.0/docs/#clamp) states:

> ### clamp
>
> Ord a => a → a → a → a
>
> Restricts a number to be within a range.
>
> Also works for other ordered types such as Strings and Dates.
>
> ```
> R.clamp(1, 10, -1) // => 1
> R.clamp(1, 10, 11) // => 10
> R.clamp(1, 10, 4)  // => 4
> ```

I understand what "a → a → a → a" means (a curried function that takes three arguments of the same type and returns a result of the same type as arguments).

What does "Ord" and fat arrow (=>) mean?

Comment: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Ord.html

Comment: @JaredSmith thanks. What about fat arrow?

Comment: when ahead and posted it as an answer with that part added.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Jared's answer is great.   This just adds a little more perspective from the Ramda side.

Ramda has a [long article](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/wiki/Type-Signatures) on its type annotations (disclaimer: I wrote it.)  The section on [type constraints](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/wiki/Type-Signatures#type-constraints) describes these.

The fat arrow implies that the phrases on the left constrain the description on the right. `Ord` means that the type is ordered, that is, that it works properly with `<` and `>`.  This includes built-in types such as Strings, Numbers, and Dates, as well as user types with `valueOf` methods that give a proper ordering.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Although I find it weird that in docs `->` represented as `→`, but fat arrow `=>` isn't represented as `⇒`;

Comment: Yes, we should probably fix that.

Answer (score 2):

`Ord` is an ordered datatype. The fat arrow denotes a precondition for the arguments. In this case, I believe it means that the datatype is constrained to types for which things like `<` and `>` are meaningful (in a strongly-typed language you'd get a compile-time error for anything else).

Comment: "I believe that it means that the arguments must be supplied in a logical order" doesn't sound right to me. `Ord a` constrains `a` but says nothing about argument order.